# Bitbucket POST Hooks with .Net ApiController setup?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to get my .Net WebApi 2.2 to accept posts from bitbucket. But BB doesn't post it's data as the body, but rather as a post parameter.

I have simulated what bitbucket sends using the PostMan here:
http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2014/11/05/shea/22.05.091712543622

You can import the PostMan collection here: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/ec562c5141d85fe7b850

When I try to post to my ApiController, I get

```
{
    "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
}
```

That happens when my post function signature looks like this:

```
public string Post([FromUri]string payload)
{
    var hookEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HookEvent>(payload);
    ....
```

or
    public string Post(string payload)
    {
        var hookEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(payload);
        ....

When I do:

```
public string Post([FromUri]HookEvent payload)
{
    ....
```

payload isn't null but all the fields in it are null.

```
    public string Post(HookEvent payload)
    {
```

gives this error:

```
"Message": "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
"ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HookEvent' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

I know my 'HookEvent' is deserializing correctly, because if change PostMan to send the payload as the request body, the object is correctly deserialized, with all fields set. Unfortunately BB doesn't send the payload that way, but as a post param.

My controller signature is:

```
public class BitbucketHookController : ApiController
{
    ....
```

Other routing bits:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

And Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs

```
        DiConfig.Register();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

What do I have to do to get my controller to accept the post payload?

Comment: Thought 1, on the first method that returns no method post, could you decorate it with `[HttpPost]` Attribute - just to see if we can't force it to pick up the post.

Comment: Thought 2, in your method where your model has null values - can you inspect the raw request to see what is being passed and how . You can access the raw request with something like `var req = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`

Comment: re Thought 1: Adding the decoration doesn't change the result, I still get a The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.

Comment: re Thought 2: I used Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); to save converting the data into a string after. The Result field returned by this call contains a string "payload=%7B+++++%22canon_url%22%3A+%22https%3........" which is the urlendcoded json payload. If I put that value in an urldecoder it becomes: "payload={     "canon_url": "https:.......". I mean I guess I could manully strip off the payload=, and then manually deserialize the JSON, but why isn't the ApiController doing it's magic.

Comment: And JSON seralizer is registered? `configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());` ?

Comment: The postman import doesn't seem to work right - but I was parsing it out, do you have dir=XX in your query string? that might hinder the ability of the serializer to recognize your data as your model unless it's part of your model

Comment: I don't think you have register the json serializer with WebApi. I can't find the that line of code anywhere, but like I said the serialization works when the payload is party of the body.  The postman link does work, but you have to import it as a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I was able to file was to use a container model.

```
public class HookEventContainer
{
    public string payload { get; set; }
    public HookEvent HookEvent {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HookEvent>(payload);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this for my Post signature:

```
    // POST api/<controller>
    //
    public string Post(HookEventContainer eventData)
    {
        var hookEvent = eventData.HookEvent;
```

Ugly but it works.

I also sent a request to Bitbucket to find out why they choose to send the payload as a parameter instead of as the request body. Since Atlassian bought them, they aren't all that responsive though....